# how to set image in proper position in layers in layer-list?

Tags: android, xml, image, position, drawable

I am trying to set image in center of circle like this
(trying it on android 4.1.2)

[image]

but when I run the app it shows image like this

[image]

but when i am writing code in xml it shows right image like 
[image]

Here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:right="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:bottom="-1dp">

        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#50000000" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp">

        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/white"
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#50000000"/>

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item  android:width="8dp"
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/news">

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#50000000"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <solid android:color="#50000000"/>

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/news"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```